# How can I turn my if-else statement into ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
    if (THIS.target.hasClass('icon-false-shape')) {
        $(this).addClass('white-font');
        if (THIS.answer === false) {
            console.log('EVERYTHING COMES GREEN');
            $(this).addClass('background-green');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('background-red');
        }
    }
    if (THIS.target.hasClass('icon-true-shape')) {
        $(this).addClass('white-font');
        if (THIS.answer === true) {
            console.log('EVERYTHING COMES GREEN');
            $(this).addClass('background-green');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('background-red');
        }
    }
```

which I am trying to turn into this:

```
    $(this).addClass('background-' + ((THIS.target.hasClass('icon-false-shape') && THIS.answer === false) ? 'green' : 'red'))
    .addClass('white-font');

    $(this).addClass('background-' + ((THIS.target.hasClass('icon-true-shape') && THIS.answer === true) ? 'green' : 'red'))
    .addClass('white-font');
```

But my logic is failing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: eg. `$(this).addClass('background-' + (THIS.answer ? 'red' : 'green'));`

Comment: @JaromandaX I know, but what I am saying is that I can't adapt what I have to a ternary.

Comment: Oh right ... you want even the `icon-false-shape/icon-true-shape` in the mix - you prefer short unreadable  code to clear code

Comment: @ajax333221 it works. Put it as answer.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer ok

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`$.toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), that handles condition internally - see:

```
$(this).addClass('white-font');
$(this).toggleClass('background-green', THIS.answer === true);
$(this).toggleClass('background-red', THIS.answer === true);
```

Or catching both cases, moving the condition in a separate variable:

```
var shouldBeGreen = THIS.target.hasClass('icon-false-shape') && THIS.answer === false;
var shouldBeRed = THIS.target.hasClass('icon-true-shape') && THIS.answer === true;
$(this).toggleClass('background-green', shouldBeGreen);
$(this).toggleClass('background-red', shouldBeRed);
```

Answer (score 1):

First we focus on the condition to be either red or green (in this case I use the criteria to be *"red"*):

- `(THIS.target.hasClass('icon-false-shape') && THIS.answer !== false)`
- or, `(THIS.target.hasClass('icon-true-shape') && THIS.answer === false)`

if none of the criteria is met, it should be *"green"*.

```
$(this).addClass('white-font background-' + (((THIS.target.hasClass('icon-false-shape') && THIS.answer !== false) || (THIS.target.hasClass('icon-true-shape') && THIS.answer === false)) ? 'red' : 'green'));
```

Also note that you can use a space to add  multiple classes `$(this).addClass("white-font " + ...)"` instead of this `$(this).addClass(...).addClass("white-font")` .